# Old OpenGL/Gluegen and basic errors on 32-bit Java. Migration or rookie mistake?

Tags: java, jar

As a total noob in Java faced with the task of making this program work asap, unfortunately I'm stuck on a loop after consuming the basic bibliography.

The scenario is a 32-bit Linux machine (Ubuntu 16), which has installed both OpenJDK 8 and 11.

And a Java Software where `tree .` yields

```
- shiftone-jrat.jar // <-- Special jar because  it's outside "lib"?
- fooModule
    - foo.class
    - foo.java
    - ...
- barModule
    - bar.class
    - bar.java
    - ...
- ui
    - Main.class
    - Main.java  // <-- Special Code because it has "main()"
    - ...
- lib
    - jogl.jar
    - vecmath.jar
    - gluegen-rt.jar
    - ...
- run.bat
- .classpath
```

The presence of `run.bat` files suggest that it was compiled in Windows, and after opening `.classpath` one can note the process was managed from the Eclipse IDE.

As far as I understand Java is very portable so there is no need to recompile the files, we only need to run it.

The only command that has worked without errors is

`java -jar shiftone-jrat.jar`

But after a quick Google search one can note that jrat is only a profiler.

Thus, the relevant call has to be

`java ui.Main`

Nevertheless, that yields `noClassDefFoundError`: the first thing it can complain about before termination is a package called 'vecmath' which is part of our jars in `./lib`. Therefore the option `cp` is added to the command `java`, like this

`java -cp "lib/*" ui.Main"`

In this case the problem is that `ui.Main` itself is not found, so the option is passed a new argument like this:

`java -cp ".:lib/*" ui.Main"`

Up to this point the previous questions on the same topic here on StackOverflow are very informative. For this particular case they are not sufficient, as the previous command opens a (blank) window that reports the following error:

`no gluegen-rt in java.library.path`

Where `java.library.path` includes common root places (e.g. `/usr/lib/jni`, `/usr/lib`, `/lib` and `/usr/java/packages/lib`).

Please note that there is a `.jar` called `gluegen-rt.jar` at `./lib`, the same folder that made the previous error vanish by providing a jar called `vecmath.jar`.

Without fully understanding what `.jar`s are, I downloaded  `libgluegen2` (and perhaps also jogamp,or it is included? sorry, I don't remember) from ubuntu apt.pkgs (which is the only one I've found, i.e. the "2"), and replaced the

`lib/gluegen-rt.jar` file with the jar from

`/usr/share/java/gluegen2-2.3.2-rt.jar`.

Again, I ran

`java -cp ".:lib/*" ui.Main"`

And now the `NoClassDefFoundError` mentions `gluegen/runtime/DynamicLookupHelper`.

A quick `(cd /usr/share/java ; grep -r "DynamicLookupHelper")` shows that `jogl2.jar` also matches and thus I also overwrite

`lib/jogl.jar` file with the jar from

`/usr/share/java/jogl2.jar`.

Finally the `NoClassDefFoundError` error is thrown again, this time because there  is no such thing as `javax.media.opengl`, which is often used in the program java's files at imports.

A quick Google search yields that Java's implementation of OpenGL had "some" changes at "some" point in time, thus the lines

`javax.media.opengl` should be changed to

`com.jogamp.opengl` to comply with our "newest" version.

I made the changes but then some other lines were broken, so finally I appear to be faced with either (1) looking for the "right" jogamp and/or gluegen or (2) continue the migration. There  may be 5k lines.

Questions such as: Is there any other option I'm missing? Is the whole procedure correct? Where are old versions available? Can I leverage the xml-styled `.classpath` file?

Thanks

Comment: Given that some of the code in your application has (presumably) been generated by gluegen, dropping in a new version of the runtime jar may not work, even if you fix trivial changes like package names. I would try to find the shared library which matches the original version of gluegen, if you can.

Comment: @tgdavies so you are confirming that gluegen requires the existence of (versioned) binaries/dynamic libraries inside the java library path? i.e. that only pointing to the `.jar` is not enough.

Comment: Yes, see these questions https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gluegen-rt

Comment: Thank you, can you please be kind enough to confirm it is correct having understood that the procedure of adding the binaries/dynamic libraries is "equivalent" to just replacing the (non-excutable) `.jar` with an executable one?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: That people can either (1) add `.so`/other files in the java.library.path and add in the classpath files called non-executable `.jar`'s, or (2) only add in classpath files called "executable jars".

Comment: An executable jar will still need the .so. An executable jar just has some information in its manifest about what class to run.